# shell-command changing the behavior of my program

Tags: shell-command

Consider the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  printf("PID: %d\n", getpid());
  fork();
}
```

This should output the PID of the process and then fork a clone. When trying from a shell, this behaves in the expected way:

```
$ ./a.out
PID: 380
```

However if I execute this from within emacs using `shell-command` (`M-!`), the output is now different:

```
PID: 382
PID: 382
```

If I modify the program a bit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  printf("PID-pre: %d\n", getpid());
  fork();
  printf("PID-post: %d\n", getpid());
}
```

I can see the proper output in an external terminal:

```
PID-pre: 398
PID-post: 398
PID-post: 399
```

However, again the shell-command executes the pre-fork printf twice:

```
PID-pre: 402
PID-post: 402
PID-pre: 402
PID-post: 403
```

How come `shell-command` executes the whole process twice when using `fork`? Is this the intended behavior? How can I work around it?

My system:

- **OS**: Fedora 35
- **kernel**: Linux fedora 5.15.12-200.fc35.x86_64
- **lib C**: GNU libc 2.34
- **emacs**: GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.30) of 2021-09-25

Comment: I am not sure if this question is better suited for StackOverflow or Unix.SE. I thought that I would be most likely to find an answer here, but I may be wrong, in which case please indicate where is the best place to move the question. Thanks :)

Comment: My guess would be that this is related to buffering of stdout. You could try to flush stdout before the fork to see if that changes the behavior.

Comment: @rsp I confirm that your suggestion seems to be correct. Good intuition.